# Azure Application Gateway with SSL bindings

Tags: azure, azure-application-gateway

I have Application Gateway with url based routing, /app1/ points to app1 app service, and /app2/ points to app2 app service.

I have domain test.com pointing to Application Gateway.
So test.com/app1 routes to app1, and test.com/app2 to app2.

Next step is to configure ssl settings for both app services (I do not use ssl offloading here). Added test.com custom domain to app1, configured ssl bindings, adding a custom domain to app2 fails with a message:

***Hostname is already being used in the following App: app1. Please remove the Hostname from app1, and try again***

Comment: i think you need to reuse existing listener?

Comment: @4c74356b41 but I try to configure ssl on app services not on listener

Comment: ah, you mean on the web app?

Comment: yes, on web app

Answer (score 1):

since you are talking about the webapps, you need to have your apps on the same webapp as "sub" apps. or you can bind you application gateway to the "native" webapp hostnames, that will also work as far as I know.

https://blog.bitscry.com/2017/10/11/hosting-multiple-sites-in-one-azure-webapp/

Comment: I have two Azure App Services, one is asp.net project second is wordpress